# how to add a react date picker no hooks

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am working on a react project trying to add a react date picker using npm react-datepicker. I am using this.state and handleChange(e). how do I add a date picker on my react app without using hooks?

Answer (score 0):

here is sample of the connection, in `App` component, its old way of doing date picker using in reactjs,

your imports are,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
```

and application would be,

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    })
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.startDate)
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.onFormSubmit }>
        <div className="form-group">
          <DatePicker
              selected={ this.state.startDate }
              onChange={ this.handleChange }
              name="startDate"
              dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
          />
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Show Date</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```